# Google Maps in Vaadin 14

Tags: javascript, java, polymer, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm interested in putting a Google Map in a Vaadin 14 (in a PWA app). I have seen that there are many addons for Vaadin 8, obviously not working with Vaadin 10+. Looking around, I have not found anything and then I ask you if there is any addon already ready? I also saw the web component (https://vaadin.com/directory/component/googlewebcomponentsgoogle-map). I have never touched the world of Polymer, only Java. I was wondering: if I wanted to use it, how to start using it in a Vaadin 14 UI? A small demo or example, if possible. I searched in the Vaadin guides but I didn't understand much.

Comment: I don't think there is an example of Google maps, but there is a great one (working and tested) for the Leaflet add-on here: [Project example for integrating a JS library with Vaadin 14+](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-leaflet-example). Maybe you could use this one instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad to give exact technical answers here, but I can list resources to explore.

There is a discussion at [Vaadin Forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/) about integrating that web-component, and you can find pointers to GitHub examples
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17235558/maps-leaflet-google-map There is also some additional comments about it here https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17842727/getting-started-with-vaadin-14-and-google-maps

However there is one major issue with that web-component. It is made for Polymer 2 so you could use it only in the Vaadin 14 [compatibility mode](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/v14-migration/v14-migration-guide.html#compatibility-mode), and in [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/npm_(software)) mode it is not available. The component is not maintained and there is no [Polymer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_(library)) 3 version available as [npm loadable resource](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/v14-migration/v14-migration-guide.html#package-management-npm-instead-of-bower).

So there is another approach, i.e. use the same JavaScript library and API that was used in Vaadin 8 add-on. There is indeed a community project for this. I have not tested yet, but is interesting. You can find more on [this forum page](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18150652/18153769).